# Формирование файла со списком объектов для частичной выгрузки конфигурации в файлы

Tags: 1с

Необходимо программно готовить файл со списком объектов для выгрузки, чтобы далее он использовался для частичной выгрузки конфигурации в файлы.

Строка командной строки:
/DumpConfigToFiles <каталог выгрузки> [-Format <режим>] [-Extension <Имя расширения>] [-AllExtensions] [–update] [–force] [–getChanges <имя файла>] [–configDumpInfoForChanges <имя файла>] [-listFile <имя файла>]

А именно параметр "-listFile". По нему в ИТС (https://its.1c.ru/db/v8310doc#bookmark:adm:TI000000527) сказано:
указывает файл со списком объектов, которые будут выгружены независимо от того, были ли они изменены или нет. Для данного ключа имя файла является обязательным.

В каком виде должен быть этот файл - нет ни слова, но на другой странице (https://its.1c.ru/db/v8310doc#bookmark:adm:TI000000712) нашел некий файл списка объекта. Попробовал реализовать подобное содержимое в файле и скормить его 1с-ке.

На всё выдает ошибку: "Ошибка чтения файла-списка выгружаемых объектов метаданных". Кто-нибудь знает, в каком виде, формате по итогу должен быть файл, чтобы удалось выгрузить из конфигурации в файлы только перечисленные в файле объекты?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ нашел сам. Ссылка вот: https://www.forum.mista.ru/topic.php?id=800753
Вкратце, это должен быть файл txt с кодировкой UTF8. Содержимое должно иметь вид:
Справочник.Товары
Справочник.Товары.Форма.ФормаЭлемента

Но ключевое, сначала ключ "-listFile",а затем уже "-Format", то есть:
/DumpConfigToFiles <каталог выгрузки> [-listFile <имя файла>] [-Format <режим>] и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

ключи -Update и -getchanges не работают одновременно. Проверил практически.